# Can't type in input field after loading a page with InAppBrowser and spinner loading

Tags: java, android, cordova, spinner, inappbrowser

I'm having very interesting problem. I use inAppBrowser and spinner in one of my Android application. Spinner is implemented with `ProgressDialog`. The problem here is that when I try to open a web page through inAppBrowser and the loading spinner starts loading once the page start to load and then close once it has finished loading the page, when I tap on input field of that page and try to type letters or numbers, it just stays in that so called "locked" state. If I type something I can't see them, the cursor just keep blinking.

To make this even more weird, I'm able to type special characters. If I tap to any other place around the page, then tap again to that same input field, then it works. Another case when it works is when I put the application into Pause status and then resume it, the input fields works.

This problem occurs only in Android platforms of version 5.0.1 and older.

The inAppBrowser java file can be found in Github at [InAppBrowser java file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java).

My spinner implementation is following:

```
spinner = new ProgressDialog(cordova.getActivity());
spinner.setIndeterminate(false);
spinner.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
spinner.setCancelable(false);
spinner.setMessage(cordova.getActivity().getText(R.string.spinner_loading));
spinner.setTitle("");
```

and I show/hide a spinner with following way:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,  Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    //InAppBrowser default code....

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("type", LOAD_START_EVENT);
        obj.put("url", newloc);

        sendUpdate(obj, true);

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Should never happen");
    }

    spinner.show();
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("type", LOAD_STOP_EVENT);
        obj.put("url", url);

        sendUpdate(obj, true);

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Should never happen");
    }

    spinner.hide();
}
```

What could be the problem here? Any tips, suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you debug the app in device using chrome inspector and check whether there are any error in console?

Comment: @Gandhi: I fixed it already, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I was able to fix the problem. The problem was the focus of that specific page input field. For some reason it didn't got the focus on itself once the page has been finished of loading.

Trying to fix the issue within inAppBrowser's `inAppBrowser.java` file by using `editText.clearFocus()` and then `editText.requestFocus()` didn't help at all. But what worked for me was following solution.

Since inAppBrowser has a method called `executeScript()`, I was able to inject some Javascript code to that specific input field that had this issue. Thus following code did the trick:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank',  location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({code: "$('#element').blur(); $('#element').focus();"});
});
```

What does that code do is that it will first clear the focus out of that specific element and then focus on that same element again.

This turned to work on any platform regardless of the version which is big thing.

Comment: Hi, How did you focused on url? it did not worked for me in ionic 3, I need to focus on url so that I can type new url and go through like normally browser can help me to browse multiple website. Can I do the thing in this way?

Answer (score 1):

If someone still getting this problem as me, try to update the InAppBrowser plugin to the last version (1.7.2).

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save
```

The version 1.7.2 has this [fix](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/214)

I´m using Ionic (v3).