# Ionic InAppBrowser Focus Stays Behind on iOS

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

**Problem**
I have a page I'm opening using Ionic4's [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser). The browser opens fine, but the focus stays on the previous screen.

This is a problem for user's with disabilities because they can't navigate the opened browser using accessibility tools like Voiceover. When they swipe, it just swipes on elements behind the opened browser. The problem seems isolated to iOS (Android Talkback correctly focuses into the in app browser).

**What I've Tried**
So far I have tried subscribing to the 'loadstop' event and executing Javascript to focus on an ID in the browser:

**package.json**

```
"ionic": "4.7.1",
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.0.0"
```

---

**Navigation Click Directive**
*Some of my inspiration for this directive came from the top SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42229432/14160700).*

```
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

...

defaultOptions_ios: InAppBrowserOptions = {
    footer: 'yes',
    location: 'no',
    enableViewportScale: 'yes',
    closebuttoncaption: 'Close',
    transitionstyle: 'fliphorizontal',
    usewkwebview: 'yes',
    hideurlbar: 'yes',
    hidenavigationbuttons: 'yes',
    footercolor: '#000000',
    toolbarcolor: '#000000',
    closebuttoncolor: '#ffffff',
    lefttoright: 'no'
};

constructor(
    private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {
}

openBrowser(url) {
    let inAppBrowserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', defaultOptions_ios);
    
    inAppBrowserRef.on('loadstop').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
        inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({code: `
          const elementId = document.querySelector('id');
          if(elementId) {
            elementId.focus();
          }
        `});
      });
}
```

However, the focus still remains on the previous screen. I'm looking for another possible solution to bring the focus onto the in app browser on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
openBrowser(url) {
    let inAppBrowserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', defaultOptions_ios);
    
    inAppBrowserRef.on('loadstop').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
        inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({code: `
          const elementId = document.querySelector('id');
          if(elementId) {
            elementId.focus();
            elementId.blur();
          }
        `});
      });
}
```

Or try with this, implement it in app.component.ts :

```
      window.addEventListener('loadstart', (e) => {
        const elementFocused: any = document.querySelector('id');
        if (elementFocused) {
          elementFocused.blur();
          elementFocused.focus();
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I gave this a try and still haven't had success. I put an alert() inside the conditional check, and it did fire that off when I opened the inapp browser, but focus remained behind the inapp browser. I also tried putting a long setTimeout inside the conditional check and focusing inside that just to see if giving the browser more time to load would allow the focus to work, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up having to do to get the focus into the Ionic inapp browser was apply a tabindex to the element I was focusing on.

```
inAppBrowserRef.on('loadstop').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
    inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({code: `
      const elementId = document.querySelector('id');
      if(elementId) {
        elementId.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
        elementId.focus();
      }
    `});
  });
```

It didn't have one, and I found out it needs one in order to focus on it. After I did that, it worked as expected.